# HTML image mapping code

Tags: html

Hello I have correctly created an image map before but this time I can not tell what I have done wrong, I understand that I have no URL's placed in but that shouldn't matter, when I hover over the part of the map I want I don't see the mouse switch to the click-able look, thanks in advanced!

```
<img src="cities.png" width="900" height="950" border="2" usemap="#places">
<map name="places">
<area shape="circle" coords="1445,690,23" href="">
<area shape="poly" coords="1118,887,1144,874,1175,893,1164,857,1189,840,1157,835,1146,802,1135,836,1102,837,1126,858,1126,861,1126,862" href="">
<area shape="circle" coords="1098,906,24" href="">
<area shape="circle" coords="408,1101,24" href="">
<area shape="circle" coords="356,987,24" href="">
</map>
```

Comment: Your area tag is missing a space between area and shape, and the coords parameter on the same tag is has a colon where its closing quotes should be.

Comment: i think it's because the `href` is empty.

Comment: ya, you right -> colbydauph

Comment: Actually those are just mistakes I made when pasting into this website, all of my code is done correctly(ish) but I believe I may have a word messed up somewhere

Comment: see here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the coordinates you have provided your shapes exceed the bounds of the image itself.

These are the values inside the "coords" attribute of the area tags.

If this still does not fix your problem, you may need to use CSS to change the cursor to the pointer.

```
area {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```